# How to make a Bootstrap side panel/div (not a menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a beginner developer and I'm looking to build an off canvas side panel with Bootstrap. The button to toggle it would appear as a menu item on my top navigation. The problem I've found is that most of the code online for this kind of stuff, such as https://codepen.io/j_holtslander/pen/XmpMEp or http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-reveal/ is meant to build a side navigation. My navigation would instead be the normal fixed top navigation, and the off canvas panel would be a div with content that pushes everything, including the fixed top navigation to the side.

Initially I would think that my code would look a bit like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="main-content-wrapper">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <ul>
     <li>Some menu item</li>
     <li><!--button to toggle side panel here--></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

   <!--Site content goes here-->

</div>
<div id="side-content-wrapper"><!--Side panel content here--></div>
```

But I don't know how the Javascript/JQuery and CSS  would look for that and how to get the side panel to push the main content, including the navbar to the left when the button is clicked. As I said, the examples I've found have side navbars that slide in, but the div I want on the side is not a navbar.

Any leads would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: you have a working codepen then what is your problem ?

Comment: just copy paste the code , or you can download lots of plugins available internet

Comment: Are you saying your issue is that the current state of the plugins doesn't move a _fixed_ position navbar over when it is clicked?

Comment: My issue is that I don't know how to toggle a side panel on button click and the examples i've found have a side panel that is a fixed navigation element, not a regular div. I'm also not sure if the same code they're using would work when I have a fixed top navigation.

Comment: http://codepen.io/jagadeshanh/pen/pNqLYX is it what your looking for?

Comment: @JagadeshaNH This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Inside navbar header change the brand-name with an hamburger icon

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" onclick="openSideNav()"></span>
</a>
```

and add sidepanel somewhere inside your body

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

and then add styles to hide sidenav by default and to open only when clicked on hamburger

```
.sidenav {
height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
top: 50px;
left: 0;
background-color: #111; /* Black*/
overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
color: #818181;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 25px;
font-size: 36px;
margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
transition: margin-left .5s;
padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
.sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
.sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

and finally using javascript to toggle sidebar

```
function openSideNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```